# What's the behavior of the laplacian of dbar operator w.r.t. a singular metric of a holomorphic line bundle?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds

What's the behavior of the laplacian of dbar operator  w.r.t. a singular metric of a holomorphic line bundle or other holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold ?Do we have anything similar with that of the laplacian of dbar operator  w.r.t. a smooth metric ? Such as the ellipticity  of this operator etc. Do we still have  the corresponding Hodge theorem about harmonic forms?